# URL addressable etn

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

We are using Dynamic CRM 4 and the URL adressable views.

We are able to access a view from the url via this url using the etc attribute (entity code):

```
.../_root/homepage.aspx?etc=10014
```

[From this link of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150850.aspx), we could use the etn attribute (entity name) instead like this:

```
.../_root/homepage.aspx?etn=contracts
```

But it fall on an error page saying:

```
[InvalidOperationException: CRM Parameter Filter - Invalid parameter 'etn=contract' in Request.QueryString on page ...
```

Is there any configuration to do in CRM to allow the use of the entity name attribute in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some misunderstanding. You could specify the entity with `etn` instead of its type code `etc` for addressing *forms*.

This is IMHO not possible for addressing *views*. Therefore you receive this error